# How to rewrite this linq query correctly?

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors, url-rewriting

```
int id =2 ;
(from t1 in Table1
 join t2 in Table2
 on new { t1.id, id} equals new { t2.id, t2.otherid }
 select t1).ToList();
```

Currently the above query gives me a compilation error saying

> The type on one of the join expressions is incorrect.

As you can see in the above query I want to join on a single integer value as you would in sql. I want to these so that query is faster and I don't want to do a where at the end because  that would mean it will get all the rows and then filter with the where clause. As I have lot of rows in both the tables it would be good if I can filter rows on join clause itself. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the same anonymous type (with the same property names) in both halves of the join:

```
on new { t1.id, otherId = 2 } equals new { t2.id, t2.otherId }
```

Your text implies that you actually want to join on a single value; if so, you don't need an anonymous type at all:

```
on t1.id equals t2.otherid
```

Answer (score 4):

When you join using an anonymous classes, the members of those class' names must match. The problem is easily solved by adding names to your anonymous class' members:

```
int id = 2;

(from t1 in Table1
 join t2 in Table2
 on new { Id = t1.id, OtherId = id } 
     equals new { Id = t2.id, OtherId = t2.otherid }
 select t1).ToList();
```

Although, the more I look at it the more I realize that the join doesn't need to be that complex. It looks like you're adding the static id in the join. You should be able to get away with it in the where clause which would reduce the join to a single value:

```
int id = 2;

(from t1 in Table1
 from t2 in Table2
 on t1.id equals t2.id
 where t2.otherid = id
 select t1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions:

This variant prefilters Table2, then performs the join.

```
    int id =2;
    (from t1 in Table1
    join t2 in (from a in Table2 where a.otherid == id select a)
    on t1.id equals t2.id
    select t1).ToList();
```

Here is a debugged variant of your original code. Because the compiler uses the property names when creating anonymous objects, you have to be explicit about the names.

```
    int id =2;
    (from t1 in Table1
    join t2 in Table2
    on new { Id1 = t1.id, Id2 = id } equals new { Id1 = t2.id, Id2 = t2.otherid }
    select t1).ToList();
```

HTH, Mark